# BigQuery - create an external table in Python

Tags: python-2.7, google-bigquery

I cannot find any documentation about how to create an external table in BigQuery using Python. I would like to create the table without using autodetect but passing the schema.
Does anybody know how to do it?
Thank you!

Comment: commandStr = "bq mk --external_table_definition=file.def dataset.tableName"
os.system(commandStr)

Answer (score 8):

If you don't want to use the command line tool and `os.system(command)`, you can create a BigQuery table out of an external source using the Python BigQuery library with some code like this:

```
from google.cloud import bigquery

client = bigquery.Client()
#Define your schema
schemafield_col1 = bigquery.schema.SchemaField("string_col","STRING")
schemafield_col2 = bigquery.schema.SchemaField("int_col","INTEGER")



dataset_ref = client.dataset('<your-dataset>')
table_ref = bigquery.TableReference(dataset_ref, '<your-table-name>')
table = bigquery.Table(table_ref, [schemafield_col1,schemafield_col2])

external_config = bigquery.ExternalConfig('CSV')
source_uris = ['<url-to-your-external-source>'] #i.e for a csv file in a Cloud Storage bucket 
                                              #it would be something like "gs://<your-bucket>/<your-csv-file>"
external_config.source_uris = source_uris
table.external_data_configuration = external_config

client.create_table(table)
```

Here is the [link to the API reference](https://googleapis.dev/python/bigquery/latest/reference.html).

Here more info about [the `ExternalConfig` class](https://googleapis.dev/python/bigquery/latest/generated/google.cloud.bigquery.external_config.ExternalConfig.html) and its attributes.